# more than 40 features causing error in kernelpca scikit learn

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

When I put the number of features for kernel PCA above 40 it gives an error like so:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/kernel_pca.py:262: 
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  X_transformed = self.alphas_ * np.sqrt(self.lambdas_)
```

Below is the code I used:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA, KernelPCA
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np

print(testX.shape,np.isnan(testX_yaleA.all()),np.isfinite(testX_yaleA.all()))
(41, 77760) False True

kpca_rbf = KernelPCA(41,kernel="rbf", fit_inverse_transform=False, gamma=0.01)
Xtest_kpca = kpca_rbf.fit_transform(testX_yaleA)
```

I am puzzled as to why this is happening, could it be due to the size of array (41,77760)?

Comment: Can you give a sample of your data? It looks like an arithmetic warning more than a memory issue given the message. Also as this is a warning does your pca fail or not?

Comment: Ill try get a sample available shortly. As an addition, the kpca does not fail if i specify more dimensions than the number of samples, however, it returns the same number of components as there are samples regardless of what i specify.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to duplicate this with one of the sklearn datasets.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
form sklearn.decomposition import KernelPCA

iris = load_iris()
data = iris.data
target = iris.target
data.shape
(150, 4)

kpca = KernelPCA(4, kernel='rbf', fit_inverse_transform=False, gamma=0.01)
transformed = kpca.fit_transform(data)
transformed.shape
(150, 4)

kpca = KernelPCA(150, kernel='rbf', fit_inverse_transform=False, gamma=0.01)
transformed = kpca.fit_transform(data)
/Users/grr/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/decomposition/kernel_pca.py:264: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  X_transformed = self.alphas_ * np.sqrt(self.lambdas_)
transformed.shape
(150, 150)
```

What this leads me to believe is that you are setting the `n_components` parameter of [`KernelPCA`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.KernelPCA.html) to a number greater than the number of features in your data.

Perhaps you are confusing the shape. **It seems odd to have a dataset with only 41 rows and 77K+ features, moreover any predictive modeling from such a dataset would be functionally useless.** I would check the shape of your dataset again and make sure you are not setting the value of `n_components` to be greater than the number of features present.

Comment: I am trying top do some face recognition and have a database with 165 images of 15 subjects, I have 77K+ features because I am flattening the images and using every pixel as a feature. Can you answer why kpca limits the number of components by the number of instances in my data?